# LSTM example with multiple GPU error: module 'torch' has no attribute 'long'

Tags: pytorch

[There is an example of LSTM for pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html#example-an-lstm-for-part-of-speech-tagging).

The below code works fine when using CPU or 1 GPU. However, when I use more than 1 GPU, it gives an error:

> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'long'

The code that caused the error:

```
def prepare_sequence(seq, to_ix):
    idxs = [to_ix[w] for w in seq]
    return torch.tensor(idxs, dtype=torch.long)
```

Why it doesn't work for multiple GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def prepare_sequence(seq, to_ix):
    idxs = [to_ix[w] for w in seq]
    return torch.LongTensor(idxs)
```